# Uploadfile google drive creates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following code to upload file to google drive using POST.
When i first do it it creates a folder and copies the file.
When i do a second time it creates 2 folders with the file in each of them.
When i do a third time it creates 3 folders with a file in each  and so on

Where am i going wrong - please help

```
function Uploadfile(e) {

try {

var folderAddress = (e.parameters.FolderAddress);
var FolderJobno =(e.parameters.FolderJobno);

var dropbox =(folderAddress+"-"+FolderJobno);


var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);


if (folders.hasNext()) {
  folder = folders.next();
} else {
  folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
}

var data1 = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.data1);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data1, e.parameters.mimetype,
e.parameters.filename);

var docUploaded = folder.createFile(blob);

} catch (f) {
return f.toString();

}

}
```

Comment: Well, have you checked that the name `dropbox`, requested when computing `folders = ...`, is a sensible name?

Comment: yep checked- I changed it to someFolder and the issue is the same- on the second upload it creates 2 folders.

Comment: Please provide an example folder and file name